# how to add new child DIV at the end of the row?

Tags: javascript

On click of child DIV find in which row the child was clicked and add new child DIV at the end of the row.

I tried to do as much I could but as of now I am able to add new child only to first row. Here is the code snippet:

```js
var pNode = document.querySelector('.parent');
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.child');
var x = divs.length;

console.log(x);

var number_of_elements_in_first_row = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  divs[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // console.log(event.target.offsetTop)
    // console.log(event.target)
    var newChild = document.querySelector('.new-child');
    if (newChild) {
      newChild.parentElement.removeChild(newChild);
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      addChildToEndOfRow()
    }, 200);
  }, false);
}

function addChildToEndOfRow() {
  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    if (divs[0].offsetTop !== divs[i].offsetTop) {

      var newDiv = document.createElement('div')
      newDiv.innerHTML = "boom";
      newDiv.classList.add("new-child");
      pNode.insertBefore(newDiv, divs[i])

      number_of_elements_in_first_row = i;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 380px;
}

.parent .child {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px
}

.parent .new-child {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1234</div>
  <div class="child">12341234 </div>
  <div class="child">123412341234</div>
  <div class="child">1234</div>
  <div class="child">12341234</div>
  <div class="child">123412341234</div>
  <div class="child">1234</div>
  <div class="child">12341234</div>
  <div class="child">123412341234</div>
</div>
```

And here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g7pq10g9/100/). Need only pure Javascript solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "End of the row" means below of the row or actualy end of it?

Comment: @ReadyFreddy Say that there are 3 rows and in one row there are 4 to 5 DIVs (depending upon DIV width), when you click one of the item in the row, add new child to the end of the row.

Comment: Can you check my answer?

Comment: I think my code should solve your problem... You can still optimize and refactor my solution - but your problem should be solved with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var pNode = document.querySelector('.parent');
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.child'); //or 

var x = divs.length;

console.log(x);

var number_of_elements_in_first_row = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  divs[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var newChild = document.querySelector('.new-child');
    if (newChild) {
      newChild.parentElement.removeChild(newChild);
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        addChildToEndOfRow(event.target.offsetTop);
    }, 200);
  }, false);
}

function addChildToEndOfRow(offsetTop) {
  var newDiv = document.createElement('div')
  newDiv.innerHTML = "boom";
  newDiv.classList.add("new-child");
  var addAfterOffsetTop;
  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    if (addAfterOffsetTop && divs[i].offsetTop > addAfterOffsetTop) {
      pNode.insertBefore(newDiv, divs[i]);
      return;
    }
    if (offsetTop === divs[i].offsetTop) {
      addAfterOffsetTop = divs[i].offsetTop;
    }
  }

  pNode.appendChild(newDiv, divs[divs.length-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this snippet please?

```js
var pNode = document.querySelector('.parent');
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.child'); //or 

var x = divs.length;

console.log(x);

var number_of_elements_in_first_row = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  divs[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // console.log(event.target.offsetTop)
    // console.log(event.target)
    var newChild = document.querySelector('.new-child');
    if (newChild) {
      newChild.parentElement.removeChild(newChild);
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      addChildToEndOfRow(event.target)
    }, 200);
  }, false);
}

function addChildToEndOfRow(elem) {
   var newDiv = document.createElement('div')
      newDiv.innerHTML = "boom";
      newDiv.classList.add("new-child");
 console.log(elem);
  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    if (elem.offsetTop < divs[i].offsetTop) {
      
      pNode.insertBefore(newDiv, divs[i])

      number_of_elements_in_first_row = i;
      break;
    }
    
  pNode.insertBefore(newDiv, divs[divs.Length - 1])
  }
}
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 380px;
}

.parent .child {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px
}

.parent .new-child {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1234</div>
  <div class="child">12341234 </div>
  <div class="child">123412341234</div>
  <div class="child">1234</div>
  <div class="child">12341234</div>
  <div class="child">123412341234</div>
  <div class="child">1234</div>
  <div class="child">12341234</div>
  <div class="child">123412341234</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added two snippets. You can use anyone that servers your purpose.

```js
var pNode = document.querySelector('.parent');
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.child');
var x = divs.length;

console.log(x);

var number_of_elements_in_first_row = 0;
var s = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    divs[i].addEventListener('click', execFunc, false);
}

function execFunc(eve){
      var newDiv = document.createElement('div')
      newDiv.innerHTML = eve.target.innerHTML;
      newDiv.classList.add("new-child");
      eve.target.appendChild(newDiv)
}
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 380px;
}

.parent .child {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px
}

.parent .new-child {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1234</div>
  <div class="child">12341234 </div>
  <div class="child">123412341234</div>
  <div class="child">1234</div>
  <div class="child">12341234</div>
  <div class="child">123412341234</div>
  <div class="child">1234</div>
  <div class="child">12341234</div>
  <div class="child">123412341234</div>
</div>
```

If this is what you want, I'd have done this way. Every new div is being appended at the last of the parent div. To show a difference, I am using the clicked element's `innerHTML` as html of the new child element

```js
var pNode = document.querySelector('.parent');
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.child');
var x = divs.length;

console.log(x);

var number_of_elements_in_first_row = 0;
var s = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    divs[i].addEventListener('click', execFunc, false);
}

function execFunc(eve){
      var newDiv = document.createElement('div')
      newDiv.innerHTML = eve.target.innerHTML;
      newDiv.classList.add("new-child");
   pNode.appendChild(newDiv)
}
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 380px;
}

.parent .child {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px
}

.parent .new-child {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1234</div>
  <div class="child">12341234 </div>
  <div class="child">123412341234</div>
  <div class="child">1234</div>
  <div class="child">12341234</div>
  <div class="child">123412341234</div>
  <div class="child">1234</div>
  <div class="child">12341234</div>
  <div class="child">123412341234</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for helping, but your code is not doing what I wanted. Say that there are 3 rows and in one row there are 4 to 5 DIVs (depending upon DIV width), when you click one of the item in the row, add new child to the end of the row.